# Сохранение php кода в таблицу mysql

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть textarea в который я записываю php код.В php коде так же встречаются html тэги.
Какую функцию(и) можно использовать чтобы можно было бы все занести в переменную и избежать вот таких ошибок и чтобы в последствии можно было бы все это дело занести в БД:

- Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING
- Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Использовать [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php)
2. Познакомиться с [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string)

Comment: Спасибо mysql_real_escape_string помогло.